# Basic Inheritance in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, inheritance

I'm trying to teach myself inheritance using a simple example in Python but I can't seem to grasp the basics. I'm trying to use the add function defined in the MathOps class and use it in the Inherited class. What am I missing?

```
def main():
    result = Inherited(2,4)
    print result.add()

class MathOps:
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def add(self):
        sum = self.a + self.b
        return sum

    def multiply(self):
        product = self.a * self.b
        return product

class Inherited(MathOps):
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.add()
        return sum

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you explain what you were trying to do? The code you've posted is clearly wrong, but without an explanation of what it's supposed to do and why you expected it to do that, it's hard to tell *why* it's wrong in the way it is and what would have been right.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to print the result of 6, because the Inheritance class would add the 2 together, but I'm not sure how to "declare" the add function in the Inherited class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code, both in the `Inherited.__init__` method.

The first is that you're not assigning the result of `self.add()` to anything, so the `sum` variable you try to return later is undefined. You need to use either `sum = self.add()` or reduce the code to one statement: `return self.add()`

The second issue is that `Inherited.__init__` doesn't make any sense. You're returning a value, which will be ignored (`__init__` should usually not return anything). Further, you're not calling the base class's `__init__` method, so `self.a` and `self.b` never get set up properly (which means that `self.add()` won't actually function).

Here's a modified version that actually does something meaningful (if not terribly useful) in the `Inherited.__init__` method:

```
class Inherited(MathOps):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Inherited, self).__init__(a, b)   # call base class __init__
        self.sum = self.add()   # assign return value from add to an attribute
        # don't return anything from __init__
```

Now, you can use it like this:

```
val = Inherited(2, 4)
print val.sum   # prints the sum that was calculated in __init__
```

Comment: Thank you, but why don't I need self when using self.sum?

Comment: @ShankarKumar: Where are you referring to? In `MathOps.add` the name `sum` belongs to a local variable (local to the method), so using `self` would change its behavior a little. In the top level code, I use `val.sum` to get the value that was previously known as `self.sum`. The first part of both of these is the `Inherited` instance. `self` is just the name for the instance that is used within the instance's own methods. It's the function's first parameter, which you could name differently (though you shouldn't, as `self` is a well-established convention).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
def __init__(self,a,b):
    self.add()
    return sum
```

Don't return from `__init__`, this means that the result of `Inherited(...)` is an integer rather than an instance of `Inherited`. Also, make sure you're using new-style classes (i.e. `MathOps(object)`) if you're using 2.7.

Comment: I deleted the return sum part and added (object) but it's still not working, do I need to add another method in the Inherited class?

Comment: You should also explictly call the `__init__` method of the parent class in the child's `__init__`, using `super(Inherited, self).__init__(a, b)` in Python 2.x, or `super().__init__(a, b)` in Python 3.x. Make sure you do it prior to calling `self.add`.

Comment: Seconding @dano. Alternatively, just delete `__init__` in the inherited class entirely.